# Is there an aspect weaver that can amend method implementation with no clear pointcut?

Tags: .net, aop

Is there any practical way to patch a fragment of business logic buried deep within a method that doesn't have a unique signature of types/members touched?

If the base implementation (in a binary-only component) is structured like this:

```
class PastaPlate
{
    int mode;
    double increment;
    bool fullTiltBoogieMode;

    void Loop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // 1000 lines of spaghetti, which may or may not mutate mode
            if (mode == 7) increment = 42.0;
            if (mode == 13) increment = -0.666;
            if (mode == 8) increment = 64.0;
            if (mode == 666) increment = -0.666;
            // 1000 more lines of spaghetti which depend on mode and increment
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I wanted to introduce another `if` statement over `mode` after `if (mode == 8)`, or modify the consequent for `if (mode == 13)` to change the value of `increment` without modifying `if (mode == 666)`.  Is there an aspect weaver or other IL-modification tool that can support this sort of painful use case?

Comment: Is this a theoritical question or are you looking at simply modifying a chunk of a compiled program? If the later your best bet is to decompile / modify / recompile i'm pretty sure

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Modifying a chunk of a compiled program, ideally doing so in a way that is not broken by point-release updates and/or can be applied by a loader wrapper.

Comment: Is that program your own or is it third party, and if it's third party is it signed? If the later you're out of luck, else if you're not going to update this often i think the decompile / recompile method would work just fine. How large is the project, i assume it's a DLL from what you're mentioning, does the dll reference other third party DLL or only Framework ones? Would be really great if you can give additional info (or better yet specifics as to what program you're trying to change)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Executable, references only Framework DLLs, not signed, not obfuscated at all, but of high enough complexity (some methods have cyclomatics in the thousands!) that it breaks every decompiler I've tried: they all produce output that won't recompile.  Some (like dotPeek) even produce syntactically invalid output.

Comment: How complex and deeply nested is the part of the code you want to recompile? If it's something simple like wanting to drop a few lines within main what would be Worth it would be to decompile just that chunk, provide your own exe and modify just that method, and then add the original exe as a reference and call that from your own exe. What type is the exe? Console, winforms, wpf? How is the code you want to change triggered, procedurally, by an event?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau It's a mod to an XNA 4.0 game.  I'm trying to inject a tiny fragment of code to provide a new key binding, but the place I'd have to inject is buried in a method so staggeringly large and complex it breaks every decompiler I've tried; this method contains the entirety of the player character per-frame logic.

Comment: Any chance you could post the game name, if it's free a download link, and a few lines of decompiled code from where you'd want to inject (say 5 lines before and 5 lines after where you'd like to put your code)?

Comment: That would be [Terraria](http://terraria.org/), bane of decompilers everywhere.  It's not free and I wouldn't want to post code without Red's okay.  I'm thinking at this juncture the best approach might be to use procedural code with `Mono.Cecil` rather than looking for an existing weaver that can handle nasty work.

Comment: I have terraria on steam so i tested and justdecompile seems to work on it happily (the Main Class decompiles down to 46 000 lines of code)

Comment: @Ronan Really? I may have to give JD another look, last time I tried it the resulting output had hundreds to thousands of errors in it, statements that simply vanished, gotos to nonexistent labels, and other lossage.  At least it didn't fare as badly as dotPeek, which generated outright syntactically invalid code.  ILSpy is getting closer due to issues being submitted by active modders though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the approach of writing these sorts of amenders (I hesitate to call them aspects, since some are so narrowly applicable as to be the moral equivalent of monkey-patches) as straightforward [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil)-based console applications: read in the target assembly, navigate through the metadata and IL, amend as desired, then write the modified assembly back out.

[Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) essentially provides an MSBuild extension point for running a pipeline of Cecil amenders, which is useful in the context of a project build but less so for patching third-party binaries.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a decompiler that can decompile to a full project (ex : justdecompile) , modify what you want in the project and recompile it.

Comment: The code complexity is such that round-tripping it through every decompiler I know of requires a lot of manual fix-up work; it could be considered a decompiler's acid test.  That, and an aspect is considerably less likely to be broken by minor- or patch-release changes, while decompiler round-tripping is basically starting over.

Comment: [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) looks like a promising little birdie.  Might have to investigate. :)